# what does "Evidence-based monitoring" mean in the following passage?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

**Research on Research**

> the European Research Commission now plans to launch a set of studies designed to further develop an **evidence-based monitoring** system on progress towards the European Research Area (ERA). In particular, the studies should serve as **an evidence base for analysis** of the contribution of research to economic growth, as well as the impact of research policies and programmes on the competitiveness of Europe.Six research themes were selected: investments in joint research programmes; internationalisation of business investments in R&D; structural changes in sectors affected by R&D investment; patent costs; knowledge transfer, assessed by patent and licensing data; and bibliometric indicators. Although the six studies will be fully independent of each other, they are defined to be consistent in terms of their methodology and geographical coverage, allowing the results to be combined to provide a broad overview.

**What do they mean as evidence base for monitoring or what kind system is evidence-based monitoring system?**

Comment: I'm not familiar with "evidence-based monitoring" in particular (it sounds like a bit of a technical term), but in general, "evidence-based X" means "X for which there is scientific evidence that it works." So for example, "evidence-based medicine" means medicine that has gone through clinical trials and is scientifically proven to work.

Comment: I see,but I think this does not match here.Because  how can monitoring or checking have scientific evidence that it works.

Comment: To be honest, I don't see how you can monitor something without gathering evidence. Perhaps the author is trying to emphasise that the monitors will be gathering evidence, or perhaps the type of evidence is mentioned elsewhere. The paragraph does say that the evidence will be retained to "serve as an evidence base". This suggests further related evidence will be added later. It also says that the studies will be consistent so that evidence from them can be combined.

Comment: On further inspection, I think this may be a case of [Euro English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euro_English). Basically, when the EU writes a document in "English," they use words that are (mostly) in the dictionary, but they tend not to be very careful about the definitions of those words. [This document](https://www.eca.europa.eu/Other%20publications/EN_TERMINOLOGY_PUBLICATION/EN_TERMINOLOGY_PUBLICATION.pdf) is fascinating, but does not discuss "evidence-based" in particular, so I'm not sure what they mean by that exact phrase in this context.